# How to change properties of particular text in a label

Tags: ios, xcode, text, label

I have a label and i set the text of the label programmatically. I want to set one of the word to be bold and the rest normal. However, i am unable to control the properties of the text. For example, I want this "This is an **example**" but am only able to achieve this "This is an example".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    NSString *text = @"This is an example";
    NSString *textBold = @"example";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    [attributedString beginEditing];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]
                             range:[text rangeOfString:textBold]];

    [attributedString endEditing];
    [labelObj setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `attributedText` property of the label. It lets you assign styled text using an `NSAttributedString`. Explaining how to build an `NSAttributedString` is beyond the scope of an SO answer, but you should be able to find ample information both in the Xcode help system and online.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a demo about the attributedText.

[image]

```
 NSDictionary*subStrAttribute1 = @{  
 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],  
 NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@2  
 };  

 NSDictionary *subStrAttribute2 =@{  
 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]  
};  

NSString *strDisplayText3 =@"Red and Green";  
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strDisplayText3];  
[attributedText3 setAttributes:subStrAttribute1 range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];  
[attributedText3 setAttributes:subStrAttribute2 range:NSMakeRange(8,5)];  
self.lblInfo3.attributedText= attributedText3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ios6 uilabel supports attributed strings, So you can use it.
For your particular case below code will work-

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is an example"];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(11, 7)];

label.attributedText = string;
```